# What is the language used by deities in their Yugas?

Tags: language

We all know that the Mantras/Slogans are in many languages but which language did gods/goddesses/deities use, based on the YUGAs and how can we predict this? Is there any Purana/Itihasa having reference for this.

I heard that Someone of the peoples suggestions are in Sanskrit is it true.

Comment: Ordinarily it would be Sanskrit for our deities.

Comment: Sanskrit is considered as ***Dev Bhasha***, ***Devavani*** or ***the language of the Gods***..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are asking-- what's the language of the Gods -- then it is Sanskrit.

From [this Agni Purana chapter](http://www.astrojyoti.com/agnipurana-11.htm):

> Sanskrit is the language of the gods. The language of humans is
>   Prakrita. Poetry can be either in Sanskrit or in Prakrita. There are
>   three types of poetry. These are gadya (prose), padya (poetry) or
>   mishra ( a mixture of the two), Genuine poetry is, however, only
>   padya.

**Update**:

[Sanskrit Verse 7 of chapter 337 of Agni Purana](https://archive.org/stream/AgniPuranaChowkhambaSurbharati/Agni%20Purana%20-%20Chowkhamba%20Surbharati#page/n744/mode/1up):

> [image]
>
> Yonirvedascha lokascha siddhamannAdayonijam |
>  DevAdinAm samskritam
>   syAt prAkritam trividham nrinAm ||

Comment: Can I get the exact verse please?

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar I don't have it.. you can ask The Destroyer.. it might be possible for him..

Comment: Well as far as I checked, the quote was from that page written by that author. So i got curious. Anyways no issue.
@TheDestroyer can you please lend me the verse if you have it?

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar Added the Sanskrit verse..

Comment: This is the answer I am looking for since ages. Thank you very much

Comment: @sysinit No problem bro :)

Comment: Thanks @Rickross . It may also mean that , during mahabharata times , people used to speak prakrat , right?